# Why can't I call a non-static variable?

Tags: java, non-static, static

Eclipse says I can't make a static reference to the non-static field Art.instance. Why does it think I'm calling Art.instance from a static context?

TDRenderer itself gets called like so:

```
renderer = new TDRenderer();
```

TDRenderer.java:

```
package towerDefense;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class TDRenderer {

    public Art art;

    public TDRenderer()
    {
        art = Art.instance;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 24; j++)
            {
                Image itd = (Image)(art.sprites[art.level1.tiles[i][j].type]);
                g.drawImage(itd, itd.getWidth(null), itd.getHeight(null), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Art` class look like?

Comment: We can't answer that question without knowing what's inside the `Art` class.

Comment: It would be so fine if you pointed the line where the exception is (if you want help with it, of course). Also, posting the code of 'Art' would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that you're in a static context; it's that `instance` is not a static field of `Art`, but referencing it as `Art.instance` means you're trying to use it as if it were static.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `instance` property on the `Art` *class*.

If it's not static (i.e. a class variable), then there is no value, as it is expecting to be referenced inside an object instantiated from the `Art` class.

If you want a single value reference-able from anywhere `Art` is imported, then put the `static` prefix in front of the `instance` declaration and provide a value for it in the `Art` file. If you're looking to access the `instance` variable from a specific `Art` object, you need to create one and reference the `instance` property of the created object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class TDRenderer {   
     public Art art;

        public TDRenderer()
        {
            art = Art.instance;
        }
//so on..
```

**Assumption 1** - `Art.instance` is a `static` instance.

If so, you should declare your local variable `art` of `TDRenderer` as `public static Art art;`

Well then it is redundant and useless. Why don't you directly refer to Art.instance wherever you need it?